# Change div width in percentage dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div

```
 <div id="chart" style="position:relative; width: 100%; float:left; height: 220px;">
</div>
```

And I need to change width dynamically. I found solution like:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('chart');

   elem.style.width = 70 + "%";
```

But that not work's. Where I do wrong ? Thanks in advance...

Comment: I recommend to specify the width in pixels, because not all browsers are able to handle the percentages in the JS.

Comment: you can look into getting the width of the reference box, calculating 70% of that and setting the result - in pixels - as the width of this div

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrrCh/

I think you are trying to run the Javascript before the HTML is loaded. Bind it to the document.ready and it should be working

```
window.onload=function(){
    var elem = document.getElementById('chart');
    elem.style.width = 70 + "%";

}
```

Comment: yep, you are right. Thanks.. One more question. Can I change property position dynamically ?

Answer (score 1):

It works well for me.

Browsers Used: IE8 and FF3.

Could you verify once other wise you may try this

```
elem.style.width =  "70%";
```

This is the code I tested

```
<body>
    <div id="chart" style="position:relative; width: 100%; float:left; height:  220px;border:2px Solid #FF0000">
    </div>
</body>

var elem = document.getElementById('chart');
elem.style.width =  70+ "%";
```